# Does DirX provide a changelog to query modifications

Tags: ldap

I'm in a situation where I need to query modifications out of an DirX Directory Server (LDAP).
In more commonly products like OpenDS, Oracle DSEE, etc. there is usually come kind of *changelog* that can be queried, which gives you the sequence of modifications performed in that server.

Unfortunately, there is basically no information available online that helps me with this question.
Can anybody with some insight to DirX give some hints if DirX provides anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

DirX doesn't provide the cn=changelog node/subtree that you're looking for.

DirX changelogs are written as LDIF change files. These files can simply be dumped to the filesystem for later use/processing, or as they are written you can invoke any application/script you like do do something with the LDIF data. For example, you can pipe the ldif data to ldapmodify and send every change made in DirX out to another ldap server in real-time. You could pipe the data to a custom application or script that filters it for certain types of operations and writes the wanted info to a sql db, or to whatever output you want. There really aren't any limits here. You just need to read LDIF.

The LDIF data can be written (and piped to your application/script) on change to handle real-time requirements, or on a scheduled basis for batch based processes.

BTW, I've seen implementations where the cn=changelog node (like you'd find on Oracle DSEE) is created in DirX using the LDIF changelog data. i.e. as the LDIF data is written on change, the data is piped to a script that creates the entries you expect under cn=changelog. Obviously this was done to provide more familiar changelog functionality for Oracle DSEE users.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether DirX supports the [persistent search control](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/10/13/mastering-persistent-search/). If it does, this provides change notification, but not history like the UnboundID change log or the retro-changelog of DSEE.